# Discrepancies in Gaussian filters?

Tags: image-processing, gaussian

I have looked at a number of different sources claiming to be Gaussian kernel calculators. However, each of these seemed to be giving a different answer for the same input.

These are the sources I looked at:

1. http://dev.theomader.com/gaussian-kernel-calculator/
2. http://www.embege.com/gauss/
3. http://softwarebydefault.com/2013/06/08/calculating-gaussian-kernels/

The third one is the only one that gave me the output I expected (using the formula from Wikipedia and normalizing).

The first one calls itself a "different" Gaussian kernel, so I suppose it would make sense that it doesn't line up with what I expected.

Looking at the source code, the first one is clearly different in implementation than I would have expected, though the last two both look very similar in implementation to what I expected. Nevertheless, I'm not sure I follow exactly what is being done in the second source.

Are these all "correct"? Are there many "variations" of the Gaussian kernel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the sites differ a little in how they present the options to specify the filter parameters, but are consistent  (to within 4 or 5 significant figures) if the filter parameters are specified consistently.

The key difference is the second site (i.e. http://www.embege.com/gauss/) requires the "normalize" box to be checked, and the standard deviation **squared** to be entered, to compute a Gaussian kernel in a way consistent with the other two sites.

As you know the 2D Gaussian blur filter is computed from

[image]

where x and y are the distances in pixels from the center of the kernel, and sigma is the standard deviation.

The first step in computing a Gaussian filter kernel is to select the kernel size and standard deviation. The kernel size k is always an odd number, 3, 5, 7... and gives a 2D Gaussian filter kernel as a k x k matrix.

The second is to compute the values of the kernel at each pixel displacement from the center, using the x and y displacement in pixels from the center pixel. Finally, normalize each element of the kernel so that the sum of all elements of the filter is equal to 1.0.

For example, consider the "rose" example from the third site, this is a  3x3 Gaussian kernel with a weight (standard deviation) of 5.5. The author of the third page indicates that after normalizing that the filter value is

[image]

The first site in the list, if you enter Sigma =5.5 and Kernel Size =3 , gives:

0.10989 0.111716    0.10989

0.111716    0.113573    0.111716

0.10989 0.111716    0.1098

For the second site in the list, you need to enter Resolution = 3x3, and sigma squared = 30.25 (square of 5.5), and also check the Normalize box.

The result from the second site is then

{ 
0.1098867834673961, 0.11171818781545209, 0.1098867834673961,

0.11171818781545209, 0.11358011486860732, 0.11171818781545209,

0.1098867834673961, 0.11171818781545209, 0.1098867834673961
}

Comment: First of all, I want to point out that I messed up the ordering of the links. I fixed it now, and I apologize for this. If you are still interested in this question, just keep this in mind. I tried each of these with sigma = 1 (which, of course, would mean that sigma squared is 1), and with a 5 x 5 kernel size. The results for the second and third links are actually very similar. I think I may have missed the normalize option somehow. However, the first one still gives values that are up to 0.01 off. Is this just rounding error?

Comment: Edited to reflect site order. The first site is doing the sampling of a continuous Gaussian distribution to the discrete grid of pixels and computing the normalization using numerical integration over that part of the distribution. The other two are just summing the kernel elements to find the factor that will normalize the sum of all elements to 1.0.